# emotion/styled - Hover on an SVG component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg, emotion

I have a a component which is an SVG with only on path element in it.
It is being imported and rendered as:

```
<svg ... >
 <path>...</path>
</svg>
```

I am trying to style it with `emotion/styled`:

```
const StyledSvg = stlyled(SvgIcon)`
   &:hover {
     fill: <someColor>
   }
`;
```

And it does nothing. Tried to force the hover on the  inspector and still nothing. Any idea if it's possible and how can I achieve that?

Thanks

**EDIT**
The component:

```
const Play: Icon = ({ style }) => {
  return (
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30" height="20" viewBox="0 0 30 20">
        <path d="..."/>
      </svg>
  );
};
```

Comment: :hover pseudo class is only for anchor tags

Comment: maybe toggle a class with onClick of course use useEffect :)

Comment: can you show us the svg element?

Comment: @enxaneta added the svg component in my question. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what your `Icon` type looks like, but I got it to work like this:

```
type ComponentProps = {
  className?: string;
};

const Play: React.FC<ComponentProps> = ({ className }) => (
  <svg
    className={className}
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    width="30"
    height="20"
    viewBox="0 0 30 20">
    <path d="M 10 10 H 90 V 90 H 10 L 10 10" /> // replace with your path
  </svg>
);

const StyledSvg = styled(Play)`
  &:hover {
    fill: blue;
  }
`;

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <StyledSvg />
    </div>
  );
}
```

This solution needs the `className` prop set for it to work.